# Why does Positive-Definiteness imply Point-Separation for Semi-norms?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying Functional Analysis and I want to understand why semi-norms don't give us the separation of points. My Teacher's handbook says: 
Let $p$ be a semi-norm. For $p$ to be separating points, $p$ must verify: for all $x\in X$, if $p(x) = 0$ then $x=0$.
My question is why does that give the idea of separation?

Comment: What is your teacher's definition of '$p$ separating points'?

Comment: There is no given definition unfortunately.

Comment: Without asking your teacher, I would guess the result being referenced is that the topology induced by $p$ on $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\forall x \in X: p(x) = 0 \implies x = 0$ holds. Though the only way to know what your teacher was referring to for sure is to ask them yourself if you are able to. The Hausdorff condition is known as a separation axiom, there are many like it, and `Separation axiom` is a search term you can use to learn more!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't ask my professor. Thanks!